# when I run this code it gave me wrong:login.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at HTMLInputElement.login (login.js:12)

Tags: javascript, null

```
let username = document.querySelector("username");
let password = document.querySelector("password");
let singinBtn = document.querySelector("sing_in");
let getuser = localStorage.getItem("username");
let getpassword = localStorage.getItem("password");

if(singinBtn){
    singinBtn.addEventListener("click",login);

    function login(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if(getuser.value==="" || getpassword.value===""){
            alert("please fill data");
        }
        else{ 
            if(getuser && getuser.trim===username.value.trim() && getpassword && getpassword.trim===password.value.trim())
            {
                setTimeout(()=>{ 
                    window.location="index.html";
                },1500);
            }
            else{
                alert("username or password wrong");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it must be either `getuser` or `getpassword` that is getting set to null. So, either `localStorage.getItem("username");` or `localStorage.getItem("username");` is returning null.